# Javascript: show selected image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to make it so when you select your image it will show it directly. Ofcourse you do this in a `onchange` thing in html. This is what i have by now:

```js
function showImage(src, target) {
    var fr = new FileReader();

    fr.onload = function (e) { target.src = this.result; };

    src.addEventListener("change", function () {

        fr.readAsDataURL(src.files[0]);
    });

}
function putImage() {
    var src = document.getElementById("select_image");
    var target = document.getElementById("target");
    showImage(src, target);
}
```

```html
<img id="target" />
<input type="file" id="select_image" name="image" onchange="putImage()"> </input>
```

This works not for me in a weird way. Because the onchange works. I can test that by alerting something on the event. That works great. The javascript works too in a jsfiddle.. But these things combined not. I hope someone can help

Comment: The image hasn't been uploaded yet...how would it be able to show the image?

Comment: @SpencerMay Using the File API. It's something JavaScript gurus love to demo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need the change event inside the *showImage* function. You already call the putImage method with the onechange event handler inside the html, and that method contains the call of showImage:

```
function showImage(src, target) {
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function(){
        target.src = fr.result;
    }
    fr.readAsDataURL(src.files[0]);
}

function putImage() {
    var src = document.getElementById("select_image");
    var target = document.getElementById("target");
    showImage(src, target);
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scb9b2Ln/) is here.